# What do I need to configure to access a web app deployed on a remote server?

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7, web, intranet

I have deployed a web app to IIS 7 on a remote (intranet, on domain) server. I believe if I use the IP address of that server as the host name in the app's URL, I shouldn't need any DNS or other setup, but I cannot access the site.

The site, called 'JCS', is hosted as it's own site in IIS on that server, so http://[ip-address]/JCS should access the site, should it not? What else am I supposed to configure?

Comment: `I believe if I use the IP address of that server as the host name in the app's URL, I shouldn't need any DNS or other setup` it depends if you have setup bindings for host header at IIS side !

Comment: Yes! Of course! The URL I am using is for a directory under Default Web Site. The IP address shouldn't be needed, but some sort of DNS magic is required to make JCS point to the web server where bindings are set to domain names.